# Do MVC3 non-sequential hidden input indexes need to come first?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-binding, defaultmodelbinder

MVC3 non-sequential index hidden inputs for model binding..

```
<input type="hidden" name="Index" value="whatever" />
```

Does it matter if they go before, after, in the middle of the other related inputs to be posted?
Does it matter at all where they end up in the posted data?
For example, can they all be lumped together and it still works?

```
<input type="text" name="[A].Id" value="1" />
<input type="text" name="[B].Id" value="2" />
<input type="hidden" name="Index" value="A" />
<input type="hidden" name="Index" value="B" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the order of your form fields does not matter, nore where they appear on the html page.
The most important factor for MVC3 is the name of the fields must match to the name of your controller/action parameter.

If you have two fields with the same name however, only one value will be returned into your action.

Comment: You mean like the checkbox/bools for example? Does it just accept the first one or the last one? Thanks.

Comment: It will only accept the first one, or last one. It depends on which one was sent back to the server first. I'm not sure which.

Answer (score 3):

As long as the hidden fields are located inside of the form it should not matter the order in which they are placed. Please see code sample below. Notice how the hidden fields are put anywhere inside of the form.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(false, "Please correct the following errors")

    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CoolStuffId)


    @Html.Partial("_EditCoolStuff", Model)

    <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
        <div class="ui-block-a"><a data-role="button" href="@Url.Action("ActionPlan", "Store", new { id = Model.StoreID })">Cancel</a></div> 
        <div class="ui-block-b"><button type="submit" data-theme="a">Submit</button></div> 
    </fieldset> 
     @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.TypeId)
}
```